# Yarn error after install

Tags: yarnpkg

Anyone know why I would be getting this error with yarn v0.16.0 using node V6.7.0
When I run yarn install I get the following error:

```
error jss@3.11.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4.0.0 <6.0.0".
error Found incompatible module
```

My team is using the same setup with no issues.

Comment: try `yarn upgrade jss`